# How to extract href link from a <li class='item'> tag?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VC02I.png]

```
<li class="item">
  "*"
  <a title="test" href="/item/a test/948507/#viewPageContent">a test</a>
   ...
```

I have the following code, but it didn't do the job.

```
entryLi = soup.findAll('li', attrs={'class': 'item'})
for entry in entryLi:
    text = entry.text     
    href = entry.find('a')['href']
```

I don't want all other hrefs, but only want href under the <li> tag.

Answer (score -1):

**Python Implementation**

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
linkList = []
aList = []
for liNode in soup.find_all('li'):
    for aNode in liNode.find_all('a'):
       aList.append(aNode)
       linkList.append(aNode.get('href'))
```

So inside `aNode` you have the full HTML Object and inside `linkList` you'll have the links only.

@marlon for the HTML object coming from the link, you could do:

```
for link in linkList:
    with open(link) as fp:
        soup1 = BeautifulSoup(fp, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: The OP is using Python

Comment: Added the Python implementation @MendelG

Comment: @JuanMedina After I got the href url, is there a way to directly get the html object, so that I can extract content from it, or I need to use urllib.request.urlopen(url) to do another request to retrieve the html object?

Comment: @JuanMedina I am using BeautifulSoup. What's "parseString(data)" in your code?

Comment: @Marlon, added the additional code to retrieve the HTML object from the link

Comment: @marlon the `parseString` is a method of xml.dom in python. To read more about this, I leave here a link to show you the `getElementByTag()` using this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.dom.html?highlight=getElementsByTagName#nodelist-objects

Comment: @marlon please accept my answer if that solved your issue